# How can I use jQuery Slider Ui and Draggable together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, draggable

Let's say I have created something similar to this: **[Link](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/07/slider-gallery/)**

Now I want to move content with drag.

So far so good and I was able to move them using `jQuery UI Draggable`.
I change the slider position when the content being dragged.

But when I move the content with drag and after that when I want to use slider button to move content, the position of content is wrong and not working.

Here is my code so far :

```
slider.slider({
      orientation   : 'horizontal',
      max           : w_width -(one_divs_w*numberOfItemVisibleInScreen),//total width minus one content div width
      min           : 0,
      value     : 0,
      slide     : function(event, ui) {
        fp_thumbScroller.scrollLeft(ui.value);
      },
    });
      //initialize the draggable
      fp_content_wrapper.draggable({
          axis: 'x',
          cursor: "move",
          drag: function (event, ui) {             
              maxDrggable = - (w_width -(one_divs_w*numberOfItemVisibleInScreen));
              if (ui.position.left < maxDrggable) {
                  ui.position.left = maxDrggable;
              }
              if (ui.position.left > 0) ui.position.left = 0;
              // ****
              // set position for slider
              // *****
              slider.slider('value', -(ui.position.left));

          },
      });
```

should I change the position of draggable when moving content with slider ?